# Equilibrium price and quantity - consumer and producer surplus

Tags: microeconomics, general-equilibrium, producer-theory, consumer-surplus, producer-surplus

Inverse function of market demand for certain good is equal to $P=100-0.25Q$, inverse supply function is $P=20+0.55Q$. Calculate equilibrium price and quantity. Furthermore calculate consumer and producer surplus.

Equlibrium price and quantity i think i know how to calculate:
$$20+0.55Q=100-0.25Q$$
and this will be the quantity whereas the price will be (substituting Q with value calculated above): 
20+0.55Q=P
am i correct with this?
I am lost with consumer/producer surplus need more help. 
edit: I have and idea about consumer/producer surplus:
consumer:
$0.5 \times 100 \times 25=1250$ and producer $100 \times 55 \times 0.5=2750$
is this correct?

Comment: When you are lucky enough to deal with affine/linear functions, it is a pity not to draw diagrams, to see for your eyes consumer and producer surplus, before calculating numerical values.

Comment: but am i right or wrong with my solutions?

Comment: The price and quantity are obviously correct. For the surpluses I don't know -draw the diagrams and you will figure it out.

Comment: I have the diagram and what i have calculated is the area of those two triangles that on the graph should represent consumer and producer surplus. Nevertheless thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equating supply and demand we obtain the equilibrium

$$P^* = 75, Q^*=100$$

The corresponding diagram is
[image]

**Consumer Surplus** is the area of triangle $B-E-C$ so

$$CS = \frac 12 \cdot (100-75)\cdot 100 = 1250$$

**Producer Surplus** is the area of the triangle $B-E-A$ so

$$PS = \frac 12 \cdot (75-20)\cdot 100 = 2750$$